# ITPSubscribe - how to make links?

Tags: joomla, feed, subscriber

i have plugin and module [ITP Subscribe](http://itprism.com/free-joomla-extensions/social-marketing-seo/profile-newsletter-subscription) on my [website](http://www.hiserproject.eu) and I don't know how to make links. I need extension which allows users to subscribe content form the website. It doesn't work now. joomla 3. Help, please :)

Comment: Try adding more details to your question. What exactly doesn't work? What have you tried to make it work? It is very hard to answer this question as it is without asking many questions.

Comment: hi, kostya :), when I try to use plugin and submit "Subscribe via RSS or Email" I have message: "The feed does not have subscriptions by email enabled". But I tried to enable it. When I try to use module and click "Subscribe by E-Mail" it comes back to home page. When I try use module and click "Subscribe in a reader" the message is: 404 error. I don't know how to make proper links.